# Error with oaxaca package in r - non-conformable arguments

Tags: r, categorical-data, decomposition

I am trying to run a Oaxaca decomposition using the **oaxaca** package, but the inclusion of certain variables seems to trigger the error "non-conformable arguments." As far as I can tell, the error seems to only arise with the inclusion of certain factor/categorical variables, but not all factor/categorical variables.

Here is a minimal reproducible example of my dataset, wvs_reduc:

```
structure(list(emp = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), education = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("No Formal Education", "Primary or Less", 
"Incomplete Secondary", "Secondary", "Incomplete University", 
"University or More"), class = "factor"), marital = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("single", "cohabiting", 
"married", "previously married"), class = "factor"), Arab = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

When I run the command:

```
library(oaxaca)
oaxaca(emp ~ education + marital | Arab, 
       data = wvs_reduc, group.weights = 0, R = 10)
```

I get the error message: Error in t(x.mean.A) %*% delta.A : non-conformable arguments.

In case it is relevant, when I run the command on my larger dataset, I instead get a similar but not-identical error with the inclusion of the variable "marital" but not "education" or other factor variables:

Error in t(x.mean.A - x.mean.B) %*% beta.B : non-conformable arguments

Comment: Hmm ok the error occurs because one of your factors ended with only one observations in the bootstrap. So the error occurs with a really buggy part in the source code, where it assumes a matrix, but if you have n=1, it's a vector

Comment: this is the underlying wrapper oaxaca:::.oaxaca.wrap and the error part is this bunch of lines, E <- as.numeric(t(x.mean.A - x.mean.B) %*% beta.B) ...

Comment: unlikely you can get around this.. question for you know is do you need the bootstrap?

Comment: Hmm... so I set it to not do bootstrapping and with my reduced dataset that I submitted here it did not solve the problem but with my larger dataset, it allowed me to add one of my previously not-working variables but not the other one. If the problem is having an n=1, do you think collapsing some of the categories for my categorical variables could help?

Comment: Yes, it would work for without bootstrap. Set R=1. For example in the example you provided, Arab is all one, so it will not work. You can always sample your variables to know it's not wrong with your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the underlying code `oaxaca:::.oaxaca.wrap` and the error part is this bunch of lines:

```
E <- as.numeric(t(x.mean.A - x.mean.B) %*% beta.B)
C <- as.numeric(t(x.mean.B) %*% (beta.A - beta.B))
I <- as.numeric(t(x.mean.A - x.mean.B) %*% (beta.A - beta.B))
```

If anyone of x.mean.A is a vector, then it will throw an error. Looking at your design in this example dataset:

```
table(wvs_reduc$education,wvs_reduc$Arab)

                         0  1
  No Formal Education    0  2
  Primary or Less        2 10
  Incomplete Secondary   4  3
  Secondary             14  4
  Incomplete University  0  0
  University or More     0  1
```

So those will all zeros will be dropped and I would say you need to ensure the levels are distributed across your grouping category. We can affirm this by simulating this variable:

```
set.seed(111)
wvs_reduc$test_education =sample(levels(wvs_reduc$education),nrow(wvs_reduc),replace=TRUE)
wvs_reduc$test_marital =sample(levels(wvs_reduc$marital),nrow(wvs_reduc),replace=TRUE)
```

We run this and turn off bootstrap:

```
oaxaca(emp ~ test_education + test_marital  | Arab, data=wvs_reduc,R=NULL)
```

And if we set bootstrap it crashes because when subsampling, it can run into the same error:

```
oaxaca(emp ~ test_education + test_marital  | Arab, data=wvs_reduc,R=2)
oaxaca: oaxaca() performing analysis. Please wait.

Bootstrapping standard errors:
1 / 2 (50%)
Error in t(x.mean.A) %*% delta.A : non-conformable arguments
In addition: There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

So for it to work on your whole dataframe, you need to check whether there are levels with n=1 (considering groups)